# Use a javascript string that is an image path for css background attribute

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript value for an image path because the path will constantly be changing, but now I need to put this value into my css. Any idea on how i can do that?

Comment: Can you please provide some of your code where you want this to happen?

Comment: So you're trying to make a dynamic image?

Comment: put your code please?

Comment: @Sheerforce yes I am making a dynamic image.  a variable contains the string which is the in this format "../folder/image.jpg".  I need to put this variable into some code so the css will read the constantly changing image path.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('yourObject').style.backgroundImage='url('+yourString+')';
```

This will change the background image of your object, which I assume you are trying to do, the question is a little unclear.

Comment: I am making a dynamic image. a variable contains the string which is the in this format "../folder/image.jpg". I need to put this variable into some code so the css will read the constantly changing image path.

Comment: Okay, I understand better now. I'll edit my answer in a few minutes. It is the background image though, not an img tag?

Comment: @dylan Also, is there anyway that you can call that code whenever you change the variable?

Comment: yes it is a background image, and what do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: @dylan Like, if you have a little segment of code that changes the string value, couldn't you just include the code in my answer along with it?